# How can I fill empty space not occupied by a polygon in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: maps, polygon, google-earth

I'm trying to create a new polygon in Google Earth Pro. I've imported some data from elsewhere (an .shp file), but I'd like to create a polygon out of the space that the polygon is **not occupying**. See the image below:

[map excluding PGE service territory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhDSr.png)

I'd like to create a polygon occupying the empty space on the California land mass that is *not* currently covered in the blue polygon (everything within the California border that's west of the sort of streaky area). For context, this is a map of ArcGIS data I downloaded from the California Public Utilities Commission website of electric service areas for utilities in California. For some reason I can't understand, the data is not translating to a map that outlines the service area of Pacific Gas & Electric, in which I'm interested.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I know that I could actually draw the polygon, but if there were a way that Google Earth Pro could automatically fill in the space between the existing polygon and the coastline with a new polygon, that would certainly be preferable.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth does not have this kind of analytical capability, to generate new data from input data. Most advanced GIS software like ArcGIS or QGIS has the tools to do this.